# print statement in for loop only executes once

Tags: python

I am teaching myself python. I was thinking of small programs, and came up with an idea to do a keno number generator. For any who don't know, you can pick 4-12 numbers, ranged 1-80, to match. So the first is part asks how many numbers, the second generates them. I came up with

```
x = raw_input('How many numbers do you want to play?')
for i in x:
   random.randrange(1,81)
print i
```

Which doesn't work, it prints x. So I am wondering the best way to do this. Make a random.randrange function? And how do i call it x times based on user input.

As always, thank you in advance for the help

Comment: the "for i in x:" would have to be used over something that is iterable.

Comment: What book or website are you using?  It's not very good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
x = raw_input('How many numbers do you want to play?')
for i in xrange(int(x)):
   print random.randrange(1,81)
```

In Python indentation matters. It is the way it knows when you're in a specific block of code. So basically we use the `xrange` function to create a range to loop through (we call `int` on x because it expects an integer while `raw_input` returns a string). We then print the `randrange` return value inside the for block.

Comment: Works! Thanks, have to look into this xrange.

Comment: Kevin: There are other, similar functions you might find interesting. See range, enumerate, zip.